# Удаление элементов списка python

Tags: python

```
lst = [['54:35:000000:10155', '54:35:000000:22622', '54:35:000000:23040', '54:35:000000:24117'], ['54:35:031135:24', '54:35:031355:300']]
```

как удалить все элементы чтобы получилось так: `lst = ['54:35:000000:10155', '54:35:031135:24']`

Comment: Проще не удалять, а наоборот создать новый список только с нужными элементами: `lst = [lst[0][0], lst[1][0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [item[0] for item in lst]
```

Смею предположить что так